# App Engine Flex environment Golang: cannot find module for path io/fs

Tags: go, google-app-engine, app-engine-flexible, google-app-engine-golang

Every time I deployed a basic Go backend application to the App Engine Flexible environment I get the aforementioned issue.

```yaml
runtime: go
env: flex

endpoints_api_service:
  # The following values are to be replaced by information from the output of
  # 'gcloud endpoints services deploy openapi-appengine.yaml' command.
  name: YOUR-APP-ID.appspot.com
  rollout_strategy: managed

manual_scaling:
  instances: 1
```

I tried deploying once and again with a variation of the parameters in the yaml section. But any of them actually worked.

Answer (score 0):

Actually specifying a exact version of the Go runtime makes it work.

```
runtime_config:
  operating_system: "ubuntu22"
  runtime_version: "1.21"
```